# Best way to pay myself from a C-Corp

Tags: united-states, taxes, corporation, corporate-earnings

I am a US citizen, and I own a C Corporation that is used to receive payments for contract work that I do.

I estimate that I will earn about $250k this year in it.

What is the best way to pay myself to reduce my tax burden (1099, w2, just dividends...?)

I figured just 1099 to avoid employment taxes, but it looks like then I would have to pay self employment taxes as well, which are about 15%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would be to pay yourself a reasonable salary, as high as reasonably possible without getting challenged by the IRS, and withdraw the rest as dividends. 1099 makes no sense, as an officer you must be an employee.

You might want to reevaluate the C election. S usually more beneficial for such an arrangement.